# if $z=2021+2021i$ prove $w_0+\cdots+ w_{2020}=0$

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> lets denote $w_0,\ldots, w_{2020}$ to be all the 2021 different roots of order $2021$ of the complex number $2021+2021i$. Prove that $w_0+\cdots+ w_{2020}=0$?

As a starter, I turned $z=2021+2021i$ to trigonometric form so I got $r=2021\sqrt{2}$ and $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$. This means that:
$$
w_0+\cdots + w_{2021}=\sum_{k=0}^{2020}\operatorname{cis}\left(\frac{\frac{\pi}{4}+2\pi k}{2021}\right)
$$
Now I'm stuck. I could turn it to be of form $e^{i\theta}$ but I don't see how it can help here. How can I evaluate it?

Comment: Consider the equation $z^{2021} -2021-2021i=0$ and think about which coefficient of the polynomial $z^{2021} -2021-2021i$ is the sum of the roots.

Comment: The $2021$-th roots of $2021+2021i$ are the roots of the polynomial $1\cdot x^{2021}+0\cdot x^{2020}-(2021+2021i)$. Use [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas). It gives you that the sum of the roots is $-0/1$.

Comment: Thank you guys. I don't understand the connection. I was asked about the roots. How did you get to that equation? Why did you compare it with zero? What does it have to do with the sum?

Comment: Factor the polynomial:  $z^{2021} -2021-2021i = (z-w_0) \ldots (z-w_{2020})$

Comment: @ArthurVause Sorry for my really dumb questions, but how did you get to that equation? How did you think of trying to solve that particular equation?

Comment: FIrst, the 2021th roots, $z$ , of $2021+2021i$ satisfy $z^{2021}= 2021+2021i$   i.e. $z^{2021}-  2021-2021i = 0$, and all the roots $w_i$ satisfy $z=w_i$ or $z-w_i=0$

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution (by far) is the very excellent one offered by Arthur Vause in the comments: if $z$ is a $2021^\text{st}$ root of $202i + 2021i$, then $z^{2021} - (2021 + 2020i) = 0$, and the coefficient of $z^{2020}$ in that polynomial is the sum of all the roots. (And since there is no $z^{2020}$ in the polynomial, its coefficient is ....)

But there are some other ways to approach the problem that may help you understand it better. First, your equation needs a correction, as you dropped the $r$ factor:
$$\begin{align}w_0+\cdots + w_{2021}&=2021\sqrt2\sum_{k=0}^{2020}\operatorname{cis}\left(\frac{\frac{\pi}{4}+2\pi k}{2021}\right)\\
&=2021\sqrt2\sum_{k=0}^{2020}e^{i(\pi/4 + 2\pi k)/2021}\\
&=2021\sqrt2e^{i\pi/8084}\sum_{k=0}^{2020}\left(e^{2\pi i/2021}\right)^k\\&
=w_0\sum_{k=0}^{2020}\omega^k\end{align}$$
where $\omega = e^{2\pi i/2021}$.

If you multiply $\sum_{k=0}^{2020}\omega^k$ by $\omega - 1$ (this is a very well-known calculation), the result is
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2020}\omega^{k+1} - \sum_{k=0}^{2020}\omega^k = \omega^{2021} - \omega^0 = \omega^{2021} - 1$$
And therefore $$\sum_{k=0}^{2020}\omega^k = \dfrac{\omega^{2021} - 1}{\omega-1}$$
But $\omega^{2021} = \left(e^{2\pi i/2021}\right)^{2021} = e^{2\pi i} = 1$. So $$\sum_{k=0}^{2020}\omega^k = \frac{1 - 1}{\omega -1} = 0$$

---

A more geometric approach is to note that the $2021$ roots of unity, $\omega^k, 0\le k \le 2020$ are points equally spaced around the unit circle. Their average value should be the point that they are equally distributed about: the origin. But the average is just the sum divided by $2021$, so their sum has to be $0$ as well.

Of course, that is intuition rather than an actual proof. But if $2021$ were an even number, the fact that the sum is zero would be obvious, because every number in the sum would have its opposite in the sum as well. For odd numbers like $2021$, it is a little harder. But if you take a square root of $\omega$ (either square root will do) and add $$\sum_{k=0}^{2020}\omega^k + \sqrt \omega\sum_{k=0}^{2020}\omega^k = \sum_{k=0}^{4041}(\sqrt \omega)^k = 0$$
because it is the sum of all the $4042$ roots of unity. Since $1 + \sqrt \omega \ne 0$, this means $\sum_{k=0}^{2020}\omega^k$ must be $0$.

Comment: Using similar intuition, ordering then "head-to-tail"ing vectors of the roots will form a regular polygon, because the relevant angles and lengths are all the same. This forms a closed loop with start and end being the origin; the vector sum is a single point so the numeral sum is zero.